# Ajax has error but there's no exception in action method

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a registration form on my website (ASP.NET MVC) which sends data to a HttpPost Action Method named "SignUp" using Ajax:
this is my script (this code will be executed when the form is submitted):

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'SignUp',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: { name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val(), password: $('#password').val() },
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Successful');
            },
            error: function (a) {
                alert('Something went wrong!');
            }
        });
```

and this is the action method:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SignUp(string name, string email, string password)
    {
            //Generate Password's Hash and Salt:
            Passphrase hashedPassword = PasswordHasher.Hash(password);

            //Insert User Data in the Table 'User' in Database:
            TodonetEntities database = new TodonetEntities();
            User oUser = new User
            {
                Name = name,
                Email = email,
                Password = hashedPassword.Hash,
                Salt = hashedPassword.Salt,
                IsOnline = false,
                RegisterDate = DateTime.Now
            };
            database.Users.Add(oUser);
            database.SaveChanges();
            //database.User_Insert(email, hashedPassword.Hash, hashedPassword.Salt, name, null, false, null, DateTime.Now);
        return new JsonResult();
    }
```

but when I click on the submit button, it always runs the code in the "error" part of Ajax, while there isn't any exception in action method and it will insert data in the table and everything works properly. Now I can't figure out why always the 'error' part will be executed! what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844798/failed-to-call-action-method-using-ajax/48848469#48848469

Comment: @aakash it's not duplicate man. that is another question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in the action method

```
return Json("OK");
```

instead of

```
return new JsonResult();
```

Comment: Thank you. That was my mistake!